# Story identification : abandoned martian village with a high pitched note playing from nowhere

Tags: story-identification, mars

I was writing [a comment in Worldbuilding SE about alien music](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/60596/would-we-find-alien-music-meaningful), and it reminded me of a short story, which I can't recall the title.

Here is the pitch :

- An astronaut is the only survivor of the crash of its ship on Mars, he only has some food rations and a bottle of water
- He finds an abandoned village
- **The village is absolutely unfriendly with the astronaut**
- There is a high-pitched sound playing from nowhere. Later in the story the astronaut realizes that it is some sort of music aliens would enjoy
- The sinks in the houses produces some sort of goo. When the character tries to eat it he becomes sick, even shower throw some sort of acid water
- The astronaut tries to sleep on the ground of a house but he sweats a lot
- He then realizes the village is *learning* from him to suit its needs, but the village is self destroying

This story was in a short story collection book, which was quite old so I suppose it was written before 1980.

Comment: "Enchanted Village" by A. E. Van Vogt.

Comment: See [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47205/short-story-space-traveller-crashes-on-planet-planet-can-replicate-water-man).

Comment: You can read it at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Other_Worlds_05v02n01_1950-07_cape1736).

Comment: Ok for duplicate ;) My god I couldn't imagine he was transforming into an alien!

Comment: You left out the twist at the end: Instead of the Martian village adapting to the astronaut's needs, it

Comment: Are you saying that you accept "Enchanted Village" as the story you were looking for? We can close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes you can close it, I wasn't searching the right terms...

Comment: Goufalite  - so old you suppose it was written before 1980.  That old, eh? It was written thirty years before 1980.  And some people on this site might possibly be so very, very, very old that they are at least as old as the story.